# Why is my website page doubling in html when I switched to a different hosting service?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is doing something weird where its doubling in a way idk how to explain it. http://arcanemath.rf.gd/MathGenerator.html

I don't quite know what is causing this problem and I've tried solutions but something that might be useful to know is how the page has the first half doesn't contain as much as the second half. I also don't know if this is an option or something thats part of the hosting service.

The hosting service is called infinity free.

MathGenerator.html :

```
     <div id="TopBar" class="TopBar">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Calculators.html">Arcane Calculators</a>
        <a class="Active">Arcane Generators</a>
        <a href="About.html">About</a>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="mathgenerator.js"></script>
        <title>MathStuff - Arcane Generators</title>
        <header id="Title">Arcane Generators</header>
        <br>
    </head>
    
    <body class="Container">
        <div class="Box">
            <p1>Basic Math</p1>
            <hr>
            <p id="BMExplain">Hello, will make automated questions, you answer them, and it'll tell you if its right. For example, whats 2 + 2?</p>
            <p id="BMAnswer"> </p>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Answer here." id="BMInput">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="BasicMath()" id="BMSubmit">
        </div>
    </body><div id="TopBar" class="TopBar">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Calculators.html">Arcane Calculators</a>
        <a class="Active">Arcane Generators</a>
        <a href="About.html">About</a>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="mathgenerator.js"></script>
        <title>MathStuff - Arcane Generators</title>
        <header id="Title">Arcane Generators</header>
        <br>
    </head>
    
    <body class="Container">
        <div class="Box">
            <p1>Basic Math</p1>
            <hr>
            <p id="BMExplain">Hello, will make automated questions, you answer them, and it'll tell you if its right. For example, whats 2 + 2?</p>
            <p id="BMAnswer"> </p>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Answer here." id="BMInput">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="BasicMath()" id="BMSubmit">
        </div>
    
        <div class="Box">
            <p1>Factorials(WIP)</p1>
            <hr>
            <p">placeholder</p>
            <p> </p>
            <input type="number" placeholder="placeholder">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </body>
```

[I've attached an image so you can see how the files are organized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uaa8.png)

Comment: you should not have multiple body and head tags on one page

Comment: its /body and /head, and thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Website automatically duplicates sections of codes sometimes. Click on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDE7o.png) and then go to properties and disable doubling or something like that for anyone else with this issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).